# How to cause a form field to be required

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a way to make a field required for form submission?

I can use HTML, Javascript or PHP to do this - whichever works.

I want to ensure that a form is not submitted with a blank value. Also it would be nice if I could make it so that users HAD to input values into certain fields.

EDIT: I don't really want to use jQuery at the moment as I'm not sure that my boss wants me to use jQuery.

Tried to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('addorg').submit(function(){
    if($('orgname').val()==""){
        alert("Organization Name must be Filled");
        return false;
    }
})
    </script>
```

And here's the HTML it is working on:

```
<form name="addorg" action="addorg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div id="orgdiv"> <fieldset><label for="orgname">Organization Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="orgname" id="orgname"/>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

This is for client-side validation. I can handle server-side validation, my PHP is far better than my Javascript or jQuery.

The client-side validation did not seem to work.

Comment: Think about your technology options that you listed.  HTML is markup, Javascript is a client side scripting language, and PHP is a server side language.  Which one of those do you think makes most sense?

Comment: even though I got down voted on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337294/alert-message-on-submit-if-text-box-is-empty-using-php/8337802#8337802), it's still a good one, and it applies to your question here.

Comment: You can use JavaScript for the client side validation, hook your code to the form's `onsubmit` event. and validate again on the server using php to ensure that the user didn't just disable JavaScript to get past your validation.

Comment: Well, Javascript makes the most sense, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: It's important to **always** validate your forms on the server side with PHP (or your language of choice) because users can turn off javascript in their browsers. the js is a bonus.

Comment: Ah, I will have to look into how to hook my code onto the onsubmit event.

Comment: Andrew, spend a bit of time looking for jQuery form validation plugins - you might find something that's basically plug and play.  however, and I can't stress this enough - you must validate on the server too.  like @rdlowrey said.

Comment: @rdlowrey Yes you do have to validate what you recieve via php, but its always better to validate too with jQuery before submitting. Your server will like you if theres a lot of traffic.

Comment: @Fredy31 right there with ya. i'm not advocating against using javascript, just that if you're only validating in one place it has to be server side.

Comment: There's no need for an entire DOM library to simply validate an input.

Comment: jQuery is pretty much required to do javascript stuff these days. What they say is true: Write less, do more. Anything you'll do in JS won't really be slower and will be less complex using jQuery.

Comment: @RightSaidFred that's an excellent point.

Comment: @RightSaidFred but it makes things easier.

Comment: @rdlowrey Yes. I'm with you on that point. JS validation is secondary. But you should ALWAYS look if your data is correct with PHP before starting playing with it.

Comment: *"jQuery is pretty much required to do javascript stuff these days."* Nonsense. It can be useful in some situations, and utter overkill in others.

Comment: Battle of the Freds @RightSaidFred Jquery is not mandatory. Just that you'll do in 3 lines what would take you 20 in vanilla JS.

Comment: @Fredy31: Yes, but my name has *"Right"* in it! ;) And your 3 line to 20 line comparison isn't true. It's far too broad of a statement.

Comment: $('#thatthing') VS document.getElementByID("thatthing")... I'll let you decide what is the easier to code.

Comment: Being able to do `$('#thatthing')` vs `document.getElementByID("thatthing")` isn't much of a compelling reason to load a library. If you like short method names, take 10 seconds and write a wrapper function. Again, there are times where it is useful, but there are times where it is overkill

Comment: `function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}` There you go.

Comment: The OP wouldn't be asking this question unless they were novice and just learning JS.  Throwing JQuery at them to waste hours learning about and applying (and it takes that long to determine if you actually want to use a framework and learning how to add it), would take much longer than the 10 minutes vanilla JS takes.

Not to mention $('#thatthing') is unfamiliar and chock full of special characters; both scarry to novice developers.

Comment: Regarding your edit: The code that your using requires JQuery, a JavaScript framework.  You must include a reference to it in your head section.  I won't comment on your syntax as I'm just learning JQuery myself.

Comment: Nicholas, you are like a godsend. I want to say that exact paragraph so many times when I ask a Javascript question, and get thrown jQuery.

Comment: This is after I inserted a reference to jQuery in my header section.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in either JavaScript or PHP.  JS is more user friendly and easier to code, but can be bypassed by determined users.  It also may not function on some browsers or with some settings allowing users to continue as if there were no validation, but those cases are usually rare.  I would recommend a JS solution unless this is a corporate website or has no room for error.

You can do this by modifying your form tag with an onSubmit function:

```
 <form action="whatever" method="post" onSubmit="checkStuff();">
      <input id="field_1" name="field_1"...>
```

You then need to create that function and place it in the head of your page.  It should read something like:

```
 function checkStuff() {
      // By default, we plan to submit the form.
      var formOkay = 1;

      // Check to see if field_1 has a value.  If not, we note that by changing our variable.
      if (document.getElementById('field_1').value == '') formOkay = 0;
      ...

      // Let the user know something is wrong somehow.  An alert is easiest.
      alert('fill out everything, ya goof!');

      // If you return true the form will submit.  If you return false it will not.
      if (formOkay == 1) {
           return true;
      } else {
           return false;
      }
 }
```

Note that your inputs must have an id attribute for this approach to work (though it's possible to modify my code to work with names too).  I would make the id the same value as the field name.  You can add additional checks for more fields where I placed the ellipsis.  This code could be written more efficiently and cleanly, but I thought this approach would be easiest to understand and modify.

This is off the top of my head and hasn't been tested, but should get you working down the right track.  If you have additional questions, please let me know.

EDIT:
I just wanted to follow up to agree with others that if you have the time and inclination, or this is a work related issue, you should validate both ways.  JS provides a better, more user friendly method, while PHP insures nobody can just circumvent the JS to break your rules.

I don't know PHP, but your pseudo code would be something like this:

```
 if field_1 = "" then
      // Option 1
      Print("Please press back and fill out field 1!")
      AbortPage()
      // Option 2
      Redirect("form.php?error=Please fill out field 1&[other form values]")
 end if
```

In the case of option 2 you would modify the form page to detect url variables and place them into the inputs.  You would also modify it to look for a url variable called 'error' and display the contents if found.

Comment: if you're not validating on the server you're not validating - you're just being friendly.  bad data doesn't need a friend, it needs a determined gatekeeper to keep it far far away from your application

Comment: Tim, that depends entirely on the application.  The majority of websites are 'for fun', and more robust web applications usually have developer intimately familiar with (and thus less likely to ask about) this sort of stuff.  So JS validation will be perfectly acceptable in the majority of cases.

Comment: This is for a non-profit org client of ours. It's my first actual programming project for a company, and I have a senior coder to look at any problems I have, and a bug tester. This is one of the bugs found.

Comment: I see; my apologies.  Then I would recommend both client and server side validation.  Gotta cover all your bases on your first assignment.  ;)  Good luck!

Comment: Hrm, your code doesn't seem to work - it isn't giving me an alert when I try to submit with a blank name.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing will ever prevent a form from being submitted to your web server.  You can submit anything you like using tools like Curl.  Therefore, you must always validate on the server.  For normal users, you can put JavaScript in your page that blocks submitting invalid forms.

Therefore:

> Is there a way to make a field required for form submission?

No.

> I want to ensure that a form is not submitted with a blank value. Also it would be nice if I could make it so that users HAD to input values into certain fields.

You cannot.  However, @Nicolas's answer shows how you can add client-side validation to block *typical* users from submitting the form and server-side validation to block everything else.  His approach is correct.

Comment: @TimG This is an answer of Talmudic importance, I feel :)

Comment: You got forgot to answer OP's question.

Comment: Actually I did answer the question as asked.  @Nicolas's post answers the better question, however, of "How do I *handle* forms with missing required fields."

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should do it easily. Here's an example in jquery.

```
<input id="required" type="text />
```

Then, in your javascript library, you have something like:

```
if($("#required").val().length!=0)
{
    formsubmit();
}
else
{
    alert("You left the required field blank");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    if($('thisemptyfield').val()==""){
        //do stuff
        return false; //will cancel form submission
    }
})
```

Makes that if thisemptyfield is empty, the submission of the form is cancelled. I encourage putting up a flag telling your user to fill in the field before submitting. Because with that code only, nothing will happen on the page. It just wont submit until the form is submitted with a value in the field.

Edit: This is using jQuery.

Comment: You're missing a couple selectors there.